# Issue regarding Ajax in Grails

Tags: ajax, grails

I am new to Grails. I tried several sites such as [this one](http://javadeveloper.asia/grails-ajax-tutorial-remotelink-tag/) to practice grails-view/ajax. But g:remoteLink is not working properly. When I click on the g:remoteLink on the .gsp page it render the new page instead of updating a selective portion of the current page.

Can anybody give me any solution?
Thanks in advance.

JDK version : 1.7 update 45

Grails version : 2.2.0

Comment: It's pretty confusing sometimes when you do this but when you get it to work it's super simple. We'll need to see a bit more code.

Comment: I exactly did what is described in the [above link](http://javadeveloper.asia/grails-ajax-tutorial-remotelink-tag/).

Answer (score 1):

@ManazirAhsan

When you used [g:remoteLink](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Tags/remoteLink.html)  its working as a method/function calling in a controller. So in the corresponding controller if you add a page to view then it will do accordingly.

So you can solve your issue by [rendering template](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Tags/render.html) to  a view page using "div" to update corresnponding portion.

you can you use render instead of g:remoteLink or render in the action g:remoteLink is passing.

Hope this will work. Or you can comment any more issue. :)

Comment: Yes, it is working perfectly!
Additionally you need to add <resourseLayout/> tag in the corresponding gsp file.
Thank you :)